# Reading Dll parameters

Tags: c#, windows, dll

I have a DLL file with four functions, I need to get access to the four functions but they don't have names, just entry points which I know. I have to figure out what the four functions do.
The question is, how do I call these unknown functions in C#(.Net)? And how can I figure out what their parameters and return values are?
The DLL is `Sndvolsso.DLL` . It's functions are nowhere on the internet.(unless you can find them) If anyone knows of a tool I can use to read parameters and return values, that would be very helpful.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Why use that specific dll?

Comment: This is supposedly the DLL that controls sound at the OS level, to my understanding. I need to use this file because I'm trying to make a custom windows shell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your DLL is unmanged:-

Using [IDA](http://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/index.shtml)

1. Disassemble the dll and find the exported functions.
2. Double click that function and its declaration will be shown in IDA.

An Example of MessageBoxA of user32.dll in IDA:-

```
.text:77D6EA11
.text:77D6EA11 ; int __stdcall MessageBoxA(HWND hWnd, LPCSTR lpText, LPCSTR lpCaption, UINT uType)
.text:77D6EA11
```

Comment: So how can I export this to C#? Mine appears to be much, much more confusing than your example

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the free version of [IDA 5.0](http://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/download_freeware.shtml).

Answer (score 0):

Parameter / type / signature information is not stored in unmanaged DLL files. You can get the address of each exported function using `LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress`, and using ordinal. But all you get is the address; it's up to you to know how to call the functions appropriately.

It would help you to understand how functions work at the binary / machine code level and how the stack works.

Here are your options:

1. As you said, find information from external sources like the internet.
2. If you can find the PDB file, this is the debugging information file, and it's how debuggers know how to associate locations in memory to lines of code. It will contain all the metadata you're looking for. But in your scenario I don't think you have access to this.
3. If you are comfortable with assembly and understanding executable code at the binary level, disassemble or debug the DLL. See what it's expecting, how it uses the stack.

Otherwise you will have to compromise:

1. Use a different library. Most practical, because honestly if you don't know *anything* about this `sndvolsso.dll`, then even if you get it "working", you will be lost once any problems arise.
2. Hire someone who can do this.
3. Just write your own code instead of using this one.

But come to think of it, your question doesn't really make sense. If you don't know what these functions are, how do you know you need them?

Comment: This is the DLL that controls sound at the OS level, to my understanding. I need to use this file because I'm trying to make a custom windows shell. So thanks.